# Sending a POST request with Ajax on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a normal button, which  triggers a basic function that prints the value of an element in my HTML to the console.

Now, instead of printing the value of that element i want to send it to my Django view with a POST request.

Here is the function:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnClick', function() {
   var myvalue = $(this).data("myid");
   console.log(myvalue);
});
```

Here, instead of printing that value, i want to send `myvalue` with a post request using Ajax.

I know how to do a POST request, the only difference is that this time, instead of using a form, i'm using a single button to trigger the request, and i'm not really used to that.

Here is how i would do it with a form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myform").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/myurl/",
      data: {
        'myvalue': $('id').val()
      },
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

So, basically i just need to know how to integrate this piece of code inside the first function, so that the Ajax call is triggered not by the form (as it is in the second code) but from a button.

Comment: Simply put the `$.ajax` call inside your click function

Comment: Just add whole block of ajax call from line 3 to 9 instead of console log in first function. In myvalue data pass myvalue variable assigned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your jquery ajax function inside into the click event function.

```
$(document).on('click','.btnClick', function() {
   var myvalue = $(this).data("myid");
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/myurl/",
      data: {
        'myvalue': myvalue
      },
    });
});
```

Hope this will help.